# NotFittedError: This LinearRegression instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, linear-regression

I am trying to use Linear Regression to fit the curve. This is my code so far:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

figure(num=None, figsize=(100, 100), dpi=100, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')

plt.rc('font', size=100)          # controls default text sizes
plt.rc('axes', titlesize=100)     # fontsize of the axes title
plt.rc('axes', labelsize=100)    # fontsize of the x and y labels
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=30)    # fontsize of the tick labels
plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=60)    # fontsize of the tick labels
plt.rc('legend', fontsize=100)    # legend fontsize
plt.rc('figure', titlesize=100)

plt.xticks(rotation=90)


ds = pd.read_csv("https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.csv")
df = DataFrame(ds, columns = ['date', 'location', 'new_deaths', 'total_deaths'])

df = df.replace(np.nan, )

US = df.loc[df['location'] == 'United States']



plt.plot_date(US['date'],US['new_deaths'], 'blue', label = 'US', linewidth = 5)


pd.to_datetime(US['date'])

regr = LinearRegression()
trendline_x = np.array([US['date'].min(), US['date'].max()]).reshape(-1, 1)

plt.plot(US['date'], US['new_deaths'])

trendline_x = np.array([US['date'].min(), US['date'].max()]).reshape(-1, 1)
trendline_y = regr.predict(trendline_x)
plt.plot(trendline_x, trendline_y)



plt.title('New Deaths per Day In US')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('New Deaths')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

I have tried to use `trendline_x.fit= np.array([US['date'].min(), US['date'].max()]).reshape(-1, 1)` but get the error "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'fit'" I'm not sure why this is happening so an explanation would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `regr.fit()` instead. Feed your data to it.